# Script Google Sheets error because cell is empty

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I tried to take a code and adapt it to my needs but without success because I am a novice in scripting.

This code allows to generate an image of a Google Maps with markers for each address and a line that connects them.
At first this code was for 2 addresses that we had to indicate in the code and the generated image was sent by email.

So I rewrote the code (my first one alone) to plot and mark the points of 6 addresses and then have the generated image pasted into a cell of my sheet.

The problem I have is that I get the error "Exception: Invalid argument: address" when at least one of the cells containing the addresses does not contain a value (so the value is an address). I need to add something after the .getValue() function but I can't.

I know that the answer to this question may seem simple to the advanced script users, but also that this code could be useful to others.

Thank you for your insight and indulgence.

My Sheets:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1eZUlQK3-4WZmhQAIw5BTLsKkbTUheCTsdKEhdG0k87E/edit#gid=1047347094

My Sript:

```
function onOpen() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createMenu('⇩ M E N U ⇩')
    .addItem(' Générer les Cartes', 'myFunction')
    .addToUi();
  myFunction()
}

function myFunction() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var address1 = sheet.getRange('K121').getValue();
  var address2 = sheet.getRange('K122').getValue();
  var address3 = sheet.getRange('K123').getValue();
  var address4 = sheet.getRange('K124').getValue();
  var address5 = sheet.getRange('K125').getValue();
  var address6 = sheet.getRange('K126').getValue();

  var map = Maps.newStaticMap().setLanguage('fr')
  .setSize(846,479)
  .setMapType(Maps.StaticMap.Type.HYBRID)
  .setMarkerStyle(Maps.StaticMap.MarkerSize.MID, Maps.StaticMap.Color.GREEN,'1')
  .addMarker(address1)
  .setMarkerStyle(Maps.StaticMap.MarkerSize.MID, Maps.StaticMap.Color.BLUE,'2')
  .addMarker(address2)
  .setMarkerStyle(Maps.StaticMap.MarkerSize.MID, Maps.StaticMap.Color.BLUE,'3')
  .addMarker(address3)
  .setMarkerStyle(Maps.StaticMap.MarkerSize.MID, Maps.StaticMap.Color.BLUE,'4')
  .addMarker(address4)
  .setMarkerStyle(Maps.StaticMap.MarkerSize.MID, Maps.StaticMap.Color.BLUE,'5')
  .addMarker(address5)
  .setMarkerStyle(Maps.StaticMap.MarkerSize.MID, Maps.StaticMap.Color.RED,'6')
  .addMarker(address6)
  .beginPath()
  .addAddress(address1)
  .addAddress(address2)
  .addAddress(address3)
  .addAddress(address4)
  .addAddress(address5)
  .addAddress(address6)
  .endPath()
  .getBlob()
  sheet.insertImage(map,5,15)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code of soMarios was working nice but markers colors was not correct. Here is the solution from another comunity. I let the code if it can help someone else.

```
function onOpen() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createMenu('⇩ M E N U ⇩')
    .addItem(' Générer les Cartes', 'myFunction')
    .addToUi();
  myFunction()
}

function myFunction() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  //var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Testing")

   // Deletes all images in sheet
    var images = sheet.getImages();
    images.map(function(img){img.remove();});

  var cards = []

  //gets the addresses of each card into an array
  for(i=0; i<16; i++)
  {
    cards.push(sheet.getRange(121, 11 + (15*i), 6, 1).getValues().flat())
  }

  //loop through the array of cards
  for(c=0; c < cards.length; c++){

   //create a new map
   var map = Maps.newStaticMap().setLanguage('fr')
  .setSize(846,479)
  .setMapType(Maps.StaticMap.Type.HYBRID)

  //remove blanks from card addresses
  var card = cards[c].filter(j => j)

  //begin a new path for the map
  map.beginPath()

  //loop through card addresses
  for(n=0; n < card.length; n++){

    //add the nth address to the map
    map.addAddress(card[n])

    //if first address, create new green marker (note n +1 due to array starting from 0 not 1)
    if(n == 0){

      map.setMarkerStyle(Maps.StaticMap.MarkerSize.MID, Maps.StaticMap.Color.GREEN,n+1)
      var marker = map.addMarker(card[n])
    }
    //if last address, create new red marker
    else if(n == card.length - 1){
      map.setMarkerStyle(Maps.StaticMap.MarkerSize.MID, Maps.StaticMap.Color.RED,n+1)
      var marker = map.addMarker(card[n])
    } 
    //if any other address create blue marker
    else{
      map.setMarkerStyle(Maps.StaticMap.MarkerSize.MID, Maps.StaticMap.Color.BLUE,n+1)
      var marker = map.addMarker(card[n])
    }
  } 
  
  //end the path and insert the map image to the sheet
  map.endPath()
  map.getBlob()
  sheet.insertImage(map,5+ (15*c),15)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This will loop through all your addresses and check whether they are empty or not and add to the map only the ones with a non empty address:

```
function onOpen() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createMenu('⇩ M E N U ⇩')
    .addItem(' Générer les Cartes', 'myFunction')
    .addToUi();
  myFunction()
}

function myFunction() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('AVRIL 22');
  var addresses = sheet.getRange('K121:K126').getValues().flat();
  var colors = [ Maps.StaticMap.Color.GREEN,Maps.StaticMap.Color.BLUE,
                 Maps.StaticMap.Color.BLUE,Maps.StaticMap.Color.BLUE,
                 Maps.StaticMap.Color.BLUE,Maps.StaticMap.Color.RED];

  var map = Maps.newStaticMap().setLanguage('fr')
  .setSize(846,479)
  .setMapType(Maps.StaticMap.Type.HYBRID);
  
   addresses.forEach((address,i)=>{

     if(address!=''){
          map.addMarker(address)
             .setMarkerStyle(Maps.StaticMap.MarkerSize.MID,colors[i],(i+1).toString())
             .addMarker(address)
     }
   });

   map = map.endPath().getBlob();
   spreadsheet.insertImage(map,5,15)

}
```

Another reason it does not work now is that because you have invalid addresses:

[image]

put correct values and let me know if the code works.

Comment: First of all thank you for your answer, about error for empty cell, it works now. But first marker need to be green and number 1 and the last one red with the last number (depend how many addresses), with this code first marker is red without number and the second marker is green with number 1. Last one is blue not red with number 3 instead number 4..

Comment: And also I have not the path